# Does the C standard define which functions are called in printf?

Tags: c

I'm working on an embedded project. I want `printf` to work with UART port.

I did some google and some people suggest that `printf` calls `fputc` and I needs to supply function definition of `fputc` to work with UART port. Other people suggest `_write` instead.

I am assuming that `printf` calls `fputc`, which then calls `_write`?

What I want to ask is, does the C standard define anything about this? (Is it guaranteed that `printf` calls `fputc`?)

Comment: The standard **does** specify that ```fwrite``` uses ```fputc``` if that's a workable alternative.

Comment: The standard doesn't tell. I once worked with a small and simple embedded system where it all ended as `putchar` calls. So "my task" was to provide a `putchar` implementation that forwarded the characters to a UART driver.

Comment: The C standard generally doesn't provide any facility for overriding or replacing standard library functions.  You'll have to look to the documentation of the library you are using.

Comment: @sj95126: But thanks to the "as if" rule, it doesn't literally have to call fputc, it only has to mimic its behavior.  A conforming program can't tell, because there is no way for a conforming program to replace fputc or otherwise tell whether it's been called.  And in fact I expect most real implementations don't, because the loop would be a waste of time when you can typically make a direct system call to write the whole buffer at once.

Comment: @Nate Eldredge: I was talking about the fact that the C99 specification states, and I quote from ```fwrite```, "For each object, ```size``` calls are made to the ```fputc``` function". No other ```stream``` function makes direct mention of ```fputc```. I think it's a reasonable interpretation that this specificity overrides the "as if" definition in section 7.19.3.12 (section 7.21.3.12 in C11).

Comment: Well, I don't think so, and I'll be pretty surprised if you can find a real-world `fwrite` that works this way.  It doesn't seem sensible to me that the Standard would impose a requirement that no existing implementation conforms to, and that would create a huge performance hit for no good reason.

Comment: Sure, I agree, just pointing out what the standards document says. If it's not meant that the ```fwrite``` specificity overrides the "as if" then the standard is somewhat ambiguous or at least confusing. It doesn't make any sense that it would be so specific and then implicitly say "any suggestion of specificity should be ignored because of a catch-all rule". Why state that ```fwrite``` uses ```fputc``` if it doesn't or isn't required to?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

C spec doesn't define anything about this aside from `printf()` functions as if it called `fputc()` multiple times.

It is not  guaranteed that `printf` calls `fputc`.

---

> I want printf to work with UART port.

Consider instead writing your own `UART_printf()` that calls `vsprintf()` and then sends the string out to the UART.

Answer (score 1):

There is no guarantee that `printf` calls `fputc`.

But you can write your own `uprintf` function using variadic parameters that internally calls `sprintf` and then sends the characters to the UART.

Something like this (untested code):

```
int uprintf(const char *format, ...)
{
  va_list argList;
  va_start(argList, format);
  char buffer[1000];
  int retval = vsprintf(buffer, format, argList);
  va_end(argList);

  // write chars in buffer to uart here

  return retval;
}
```